# Library for Phi correlation coefficient in python?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, categorical-data, correlation

I want to calculate correlation b/w categorical features in my data. I reviewed the literature and found phi coefficient can be used for this purpose. I found one library called phik in python [enter link description here](https://phik.readthedocs.io/en/latest/phik.html). But when I'm using this library it not only gives phi coefficient but they suggest checking on the significance score and not only the phi coefficient. My questions are :

1. How should we go about selecting the features based on this phi coefficient correlation. Specifically as there is a significance score also, how does one go about applying a threshold on that to select features with less correlation.
2. is there any other library in python which can help me calculate phi coefficient b/w categorical features, as phik library have also done some mathematical modifications at backend.

Thanks